# How do I bevel this object if subdivision surface modiefier is already applied?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

[image: Subdivision applied object]

I have made this shape in blender, as you can see I have used subdivision surface modifier.
I want to bevel the right corners of this model.
[image]
But when I try to apply this bevel to my model bevel doesn't work.

How do I bevel the right hand side corners and apply subdivision surface at the same time ?

Can anyone tell me what should be my approach ?

Regards
Prachu

Comment: What about selecting the desired edges and bevel them using the edit mode (NOT modifier), couldnt be?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it can suit to let the subdivision do the bevel for you.. the resulting curve is not quite the same shape as one you would have made yourself, and can be subtly altered by holding loops a fair way back from the 'bevelled' edge.

If you don't put the holding loops in, though, the edges between  the bevels are slightly curved, and the large face is not as flat.

[image]

The bottom surface is the top topology with three levels of subdivision.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean (? I'm not sure) you want a round corner and give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object, your topology is not good, here is a way to do it (don't forget to press *Smooth Shading* in the *Tool* menu), but maybe there are better ones?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it's very hard to me to understand your problem. I just showed how to make a bevel on a corner of an object that has a Subsurf modifier but I'm not even sure that's what you want (?). About the file: I put a link below, but it's very easy to do, you need to select the angle, ctrl B to create a bevel, then use J to create edges between vertices, W > Subdivide to add some vertices to some edges, GG to slide vertices along edges, ctrl R to create additional edge loops to sharp the edges, etc... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5330